# Error (2014. Commands out of querys) with all complex querys on MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

On all complex querys (returning many results and running long) I get the same error after some time: Error Code: 2014. Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

e.g.:

```
## Prozedur Droppen
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ifob.uspUpdateHeatStatsAll;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
## Prozedur erstellen
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `uspUpdateHeatStatsAll`()
BEGIN

    ## Update table
    DECLARE _HeatNrDINT int;
    DECLARE _count int;
    DECLARE _act int;

      # Bearbeitungsliste erstellen
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmptblColumns;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptblColumns (`HeatNrDINT` int) ENGINE = MEMORY;
    # Delete old data
    # Add columns to workertable
    INSERT INTO tmptblColumns (`HeatNrDINT`) SELECT DISTINCT `Input.General.Values.HeatNrDINT` from tblmeasuringvaluesyear;
    SET _count = (SELECT count(*) FROM tmptblColumns);
    SET _act = 1;
    #debug
    #SELECT * FROM tmptblColumns;

    BEGIN
        DECLARE _done BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT `HeatNrDINT` FROM `tmptblColumns`;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET _done = TRUE;

        #Alte Daten löschen
        OPEN column_cursor;
        FETCH column_cursor INTO _HeatNrDINT;
        read_loop: LOOP
            SELECT CONCAT('Bearbeite:',_HeatNrDINT,'(',_act,'/', _count,')') as `Status`;
            CALL uspUpdateHeatStats(_HeatNrDINT);
            SET _act = _act+1;
            FETCH column_cursor INTO _HeatNrDINT;
            IF _done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE column_cursor;
        # Execute STMT
      END;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

#TEST
CALL uspUpdateHeatStatsAll();
SELECT * FROM tblheatdata;
```

works for 50 loops and then it quits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also run into this problem. The maximum number of result sets in MySQL Workbench [defaults to 50](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-editor.html). It will crash after 50 because the previous results have not been retrieved.